# Можно ли увеличить высоту actionBar темы программно?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

У меня в приложении стоит тема: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Есть необходимость поменять высоту программно и отобразить в этом тулбаре imageView и два текстовых поля. Перегуглил кучу всего, но так и не нашел решения. Я думал что можно взять getSupportActioBar дальше сетить ему высоту, но так нельзя. Дальше решил что можно через разметку задать сразу и высоту и сделать два поля и тд. Но почему-то не получается сетить layout таким образом:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setCustomView(R.layout.personal_page_toolbar);
```

но так ничего не сетится почему-то. Не могу понять как решить данную проблему. Суть в том что у меня в активности висит контейнер и в нем фрагменты, и только при определенном фрагменте мне нужно сделать такое.

Comment: По-моему `get/setSupportActionBar` используется с саппортным тулбаром, объявленным разметке - то есть если Вы его не засеттили то и get ничего не вернёт. А `ActionBar` - это компонент из стандартного фреймворка и его добывают методом `getActionBar()`